# all android classes should be extended from Activity?

Tags: android, mobile, android-activity

in android, should every class extends Activity? I have a class for reading file. and it does not extends from Activty class. But it does not work. So I want to learn all classes should be extended from Activity?

Comment: No, is the answer. As @mah has said, the `Activity` class in Android is for providing a user-interface (UI). If you have a class which "...does not work" then post your code and explain 'why' it does not work.

Answer (score 5):

Only classes which are Activity-based UIs should extend from Activity. If your class for reading does not also have a UI to manage, as a stand-alone component, it isn't an Activity.